# How to get a person's friends and followers on Twitter using the tweepy library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

The `getting_friends_follwers()` function below works if I remove the value 100 from (cursor2.items (100)). My goal is to get these names (followers and friends) and save them in a "amigos.txt" file.

The problem: The name `screen_name` has a gigantic amount of friends and followers and, thus, the connection is closed by Twitter. I thought about trying to capture the names 100 out of 100 (hence the value 100 in the call to cursor2) but the following error occurs:

```
builtins.TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'User' and 'User'
```

How to fix it?

```
Meu = []
def getting_friends_follwers():
    # Get list of followers and following for group of users tweepy
    f = open("amigos.txt","w")
    cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, screen_name="Carlos")
    cursor2 = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="Carlos")
##    for user in cursor.items():
##        print('friend: ' + user.screen_name)

    for user in sorted(cursor2.items(100)):###funciona se eu tirar este valor!!!
         f.write(str(user.screen_name)+ "\n")


         print('follower: ' + user.screen_name)

f.close()
getting_friends_follwers()
```

Comment: Btw, you call the function after closing the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are passing the items to the "sorted" function, which is trying to sort those "User" objects but it is not able to do that as there's no instructions about how to "sort" tweepy user objects.

If you remove "sorted" then the program would work fine.

Also, you close the file before calling the function. I would suggest you to use the "with open" syntax to assure the file gets closed properly.

You could write your code like this:

```py
def getting_friends_follwers(file):
    # Get list of followers and following for group of users tweepy
    cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, screen_name="Carlos")
    cursor2 = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="Carlos")
##    for user in cursor.items():
##        print('friend: ' + user.screen_name)

    for user in cursor2.items(100):###funciona se eu tirar este valor!!!
         file.write(str(user.screen_name)+ "\n")
         print('follower: ' + user.screen_name)

with open("amigos.txt", "w") as file:
    getting_friends_follwers(file)
```

Comment: Tks the "screen_name" has lots of friends and the program reaches  Connection aborted. How cal I get the names little by little?

Comment: Tweepy's cursor does have that timeout problem. The community is aware of it. You can implement a "backoff" kind of feature which waits and tries again if connection is aborted. However there's no guarantee that the cursor will maintain its integrity. You can follow some "solutions" which worked for some people over here https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/617, btw this is also the issue thread on Tweepy's github for the issue you are facing, keep an eye on it if you want more permanent solution

Comment: Tks. Is there another python library to do it?

Comment: There are other libraries but none of them are as well documented and as easy to use as Tweepy. 

One API that I found on google was https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html# this has a feature of sleeping when twitter blocks the requests. Maybe that'll be helpful.